# LINQ: Get filtered objects with filtered subcollection items?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, orm

I have class **Goal**, which contains collecion of objects **ProgressItems**. Progress items has property **Date**.

I want to get only goals which has progress items with date between specified range. **Goals** should have included **ProgressItems**, but only with passed **Date** condition.

How should I modify my LINQ?

```
        var goalIds = _dbContext.GoalProgressItems
            .Include(p => p.Goal)
            .Where(p => p.Date >= range.From && p.Date <= range.To)
            .Select(p => p.Id);

        var goals = _dbContext.Goals
            .Include(p => p.ProgressItems)
            .Where(p => goalIds.Contains(p.Id))
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to do `.Join()` on the two streams.  Since `goalIds` is filtered already, it won't have any reference to `Goals` that doesn't have an item within the specified range, and, thus, `.Join()` will filter out items in `goals` that don't have matching entry(-ies) in `goalIds`.

```
    var goalIds = _dbContext.GoalProgressItems
        .Include(p => p.Goal)
        .Where(p => p.Date >= range.From && p.Date <= range.To);

    var goals = _dbContext.Goals
        .Include(p => p.ProgressItems)
        .Join(goalIds, g => g, gpi => gpi.GoalId, (g, gpi) => g);
```

and so now `goals` should contain only those goes that have progress items that are within desired range.

Comment: It's not working. In GoalProgresItem entity I don't have property "Goal_Id", instead of it I have only object Goal. My join looks like below. It could be reason why query return all progress items.

.Join(goalProgressItemsQuery, g => g.Id, gpi => gpi.Goal.Id, (g, gpi) => g)

Comment: I suspect `gpi.Goal.Id` would cause Goal to load that may not be necessary.  And in order to load `Goal`, your PI has to have an id foreign key reference, so there should be some ID exposed on the model, but if not, `gpi.Golad.Id` would work as well.  I had to guess b/c it wasn't available in your example.

Answer (score 0):

How about this query?

```
dbContext.Goals.Include(p => p.ProgressItems)
      .Where(p => p.ProgressItems.Any(pr => pr.Date >= range.From && pr.Date <= range.To))
      .ToList();
```

Note that the using the join as mentioned by LB2 would probably generate a more efficient SQL query (provided you can change the model the perform the join).